# Socket.io, code returns error net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT consistently

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

This is a rewrited question from a previous one about a more specific issue, however, I believe I've narrowed it down to a single error code that I get with my reformatted code. While I've done a lot of research on discovering the up-to-date syntax for both the client-side and server-side scripts, it still returns the same error which leads me to believe it might have something to do with my server set-up in some way. While I hope this is not the case, I figured posting a more specific question might help narrow down the issue for any potential solvers.

Server-side code has changed, and I *believe* it has no issues in syntax at all as (at least the relevant part for opening up a socket io pathway) is copied straight from a different person who provided current good format for the server-side script. It is posted below

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected');
});

io.on('disconnect', function(data){
    console.log('Client disconnected');  
    });

server.listen(8002, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8002');
});

module.exports = app;
```

For anyone wondering, port 8002 is the port that I opened specifically for nodejs and doesn't interfere with any other functionality, AFAIK.

Now onto the client-side code, which is where I postulate the problem is located within. It has seen several changes to try and conform to recent solutions to others issues of similar types, however, it still does not work.

```
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            const socket = io('http://mywebsite.com:8002');
            socket.on("connect",function(){
                console.log("socket connected");
            });
            socket.on("disconnect",function(){
                console.log("socket disconnected");
            });
        </script>
```

When navigating to the site, nothing is logged to either the server-side or the client-side console, besides the "listening on *:8002" which obviously only indicates that the server-side script had no issues loading. This obviously indicates that no connection between the server is created from the client, but as the port open is 8002 (the port the client points to) I am unsure as to why it doesn't create a connection. After a few seconds on the website, multiple `GET http://mywebsite.com:8002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mys3YWR net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` errors appear sourcing from index.js:83.

This was supposed to be the end of my question, but the plot thickens; I just got back from going to the store and noticed that when I turned my computer off, it connected then disconnected, logging both a "client connected" on the server terminal and a "socket connected" on the website. Why it would create the socket when I turned my computer off, I have no clue, which is where I'm hoping someone could give me a clue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can start by adding a handle for the `error` event in the client: `socket.on('error', function(e) {console.log('error', e);});` and see if that shows anything.  When you say you  turned your computer off, was that the client or the server?

Comment: The server is a VPS not located on my computer so that would just be the client, I added that line you asked me to include, nothing gets logged into console except the same error mentioned in the original post in addition to a new error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT from :8002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MysIrF5:1` Based on this new error and the absence of an error I propose that it isn't loading the socket io dependency but I do not know what that would be as the link is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution, and it was almost so simple I feel like an idiot. I'm sure some of the problems I had were due to bad code in my previous question about a similar topic, but in this case (with the code I listed which is verified working in 2019 with socket.io 2.3.0) my problem was I specified the io connection as mywebsite.com:8002, replacing it with the websites IP:8002 made the code work. Why this made all the difference, I have some guesses but nothing solid, figuring that since the website has two nameservers it might have been relayed onto the other one which doesn't have any of the node dependencies in it.

Comment: This worked for a while, all day up to this point. Just turned off the node file because I was updating it and turned it back on again and the problem has returned. Didn't change anything in file as I reverted back to old file and problem is still the same. What the hell.

Comment: Update; this code still works, I suppose I have some backend server settings issues that have caused the issues with restarting the nodejs, I have since just had it running 24/7 on the server and streaming updates to its code as they occur. I went to work today and upon returning the socket connection worked flawlessly, not sure what the issue is exactly but for the moment this admittedly not ideal workaround works just fine.